# jQuery merge() and array.length data type

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been looking through some of the jQuery source and I ran across the `merge` function.  Here is the source code for it:

```
function merge(first, second) {
    var l = second.length,
        i = first.length,
        j = 0;

    if (typeof l === "number") {
        for (; j < l; j++) {
            first[i++] = second[j];
        }
    } else {
        while (second[j] !== undefined) {
            first[i++] = second[j++];
        }
    }

    first.length = i;

    return first;
}
```

While I understand the code, something doesn't make sense to me.  Particularly the `if (typeof l === "number")` part.  I have tried passing an array to this function when I have manually changed the `.length` property to something like `"3"` and checked it's type and I still get a type of `number`.

My question is when would the `length` property ever not be a type of `number` in JavaScript arrays?

Comment: For example: `{length: 'foo'}`. I believe this is only a simple test for arrays or array-like objects.

Comment: @FelixKling Is this an object literal or you setting the `length` property of something?

Comment: It's an object literal. Any object can have a (non-numeric) `length` property, only the ones of arrays and functions are special.

Comment: @SethenMaleno Yes, he's creating an object with one property named length, whose type is not number.

Comment: @Sethen, to elaborate, that's to support array-like objects that do not expose a `length` property but whose other members can still be accessed through sequential indexing. In that case, iteration stops when the first `undefined` value is returned.

Comment: What's an example of an array-like object?

Comment: Examples: `{0: 'foo', length: 1}`, the `arguments` object in each function, every jQuery object, `NodeList`s and `HTMLCollection`s (e.g. returned by `getElementsByTagName`). Basically any object that has a numeric `length` property and numeric properties.

Comment: @FelixKling Ah, so it's just an object literal with integer based indexing?  Do you think instead of using this approach, we could've checked to make sure both arguments were the array date type instead??

Comment: It depends on what the purpose of the function is, how it is used. It makes sense to make the function generic.

Comment: @FelixKling If you were to pass `{0: 0}, {1: 1}` this merge function wouldn't work. This is why I am confused as to why we're checking type of the `length` property when it doesn't work for array-like objects anyways

Comment: @Sethen, I don't think this is the kind of object this method targets. I suspect it is about values accumulated in an object literal instead of an array, like `var i = 0, o = {}; while (something()) { o[i++] = somevalue(); }`. Maybe that's faster than `push()`ing into an array, I don't know.

Comment: `second` doesn't even need to have a `length`; in that case, `typeof l` will be `"undefined"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `merge` function you're looking at is a public jQuery method: `jQuery.merge()` or `$.merge()`. So you might think that reading [the `jQuery.merge()` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.merge/) would shed some light on this question.

Unfortunately, it doesn't, at least as of this writing.

As explained in the other answers and comments, this test for a numeric `length` property will always succeed when `second` is an `Array`, because an `Array` will always have a numeric `length`. The only possible reason to have this test in the code is to handle the case where `second` is *not* an `Array`.

But the documentation doesn't mention this case at all. It only discusses cases where both `first` and `second` are both native JavaScript `Array` objects, not "array-like" objects.

If this documented use was all this function did, it would be pretty useless, since JavaScript provides a perfectly good native `array.concat(array)` method that can be used instead of `jQuery.merge()`.

So it would seem that the real purpose of this function must be in its *undocumented* use. Let's try it out in the Chrome console on the [jQuery.merge() doc page](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.merge/). Open the developer tools, select the Console tab, and enter an example similar to the ones in the doc:

```js
jQuery.merge( [ 'a', 'b' ], [ 'c', 'd' ] )
```

and then try the same thing with `.concat()`:

```js
[ 'a', 'b' ].concat([ 'c', 'd' ])
```

They will both log exactly the same thing:

```
["a", "b", "c", "d"]
```

Since this is jQuery, the most likely case of an "array-like" object would be a jQuery object. For example, that doc page currently has three `<h3>` elements on it, so we can get them with:

```js
$('h3')
```

That will log:

```
[►<h3>…</h3>, ►<h3>…</h3>, ►<h3>…</h3>]
```

That isn't an array, but it looks a lot like one, and it does have a numeric `length` property which we can check with:

```js
typeof $('h3').length
```

So let's try it with `concat`:

```js
['x'].concat( $('h3') )
```

Oops. That should give us an array of four elements, 'x' followed by the three DOM elements. Instead, i gives us an array of *two* element, with the jQuery object as the second element:

```
[►e.fn.init[3] ]
```

It looks like jQuery's "array-like" object isn't array-like enough for `.concat()`.

Oddly enough, some other array methods do with work jQuery's array-like object, such as `.slice()`:

```js
Array.prototype.slice.call( $('h3'), 1 )
```

That logs the correct result, an array of two elements:

```
[►<h3>…</h3>, ►<h3>…</h3>]
```

So let's try `$.merge()`:

```js
$.merge( ['x'], $('h3') )
```

Sure enough, that logs what we expected:

```
["x", ►<h3>…</h3>, ►<h3>…</h3>, ►<h3>…</h3>]
```

There's also another way to do this. jQuery provides a `.toArray()` method, so we can do the same thing by combining that with `.concat()`:

```js
['x'].concat( $('h3').toArray() )
```

That logs the same thing as the `$.merge()` call.

What if `first` is a jQuery object?

```js
$.merge( $('h1'), $('h3') )
```

That works too:

```
[<h1 class="entry-title">jQuery.merge()</h1>,
   ►<h3>…</h3>, ►<h3>…</h3>, ►<h3>…</h3>]
```

So it would appear that this is the purpose of this method: to do `array.concat()`-like operations on jQuery objects.

But wait! This still doesn't answer the question of why that extra code is in there for the non-numeric `.length`. After all, a jQuery object *does* have a numeric `.length`, so we still haven't exercised the code for the non-numeric case.

So this part of the code must be there for some purpose *other* than handling jQuery objects. What could that be?

We can find out a bit more by going to the [jQuery source repository](https://github.com/jquery/jquery) and locating the file in the `src` directory that has the `merge:` code (it happens to be `core.js`). Then [use the **Blame** button](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blame/master/src/core.js) and search within the page for the `merge:` code to see what the commit comment for the code is. Again, the code we're wondering about now is the `else` clause, where `typeof l` is not a number.

[The commit](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/commit/715d1c5a30cc4986018bbf063713f14c34c3e258) was by [John Resig](https://github.com/jeresig) on 2009-12-09, with a comment "Rewrote merge() (faster and less obtuse now). Fixed #5610." There's a bit of controversy in the discussion on that page:

> Well, your version is faster only in the special (very rare) case of overwritted length property. In all other cases, my one was little faster.
>   Also you are not considering the case obj.length = new Number(N) - but yeah it is not so relevant I suppose.

This helps explain it a little, but what is issue #5610? Maybe that will tell us. Don't see an issue tracker on the GitHub repo? jQuery has its own [issue tracker](http://bugs.jquery.com/) and if we search there for `#5610` (or do a Google search for `jquery issue 5610`, we finally find [issue #5610](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/5610):

---

MAKEARRAY CAN CAUSE BROWSER CRASH ON NON ARRAY OBJECTS WITH LENGTH PROPERTY

Description

I haven't tested this with 1.4

For an object with a length property that casts to a non-zero positive integer, makeArray will create an array with that length filled with undefined.

```
>>> jQuery.makeArray({'length': '5'})
[undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]
```

If the length property is zero, negative or a decimal then Firefox and Safari both hang. (FF shows the unresponsive script error, Safari hangs until it crashes)

```
>>> jQuery.makeArray({'length': '0'})
>>> jQuery.makeArray({'length': '5.2'})
>>> jQuery.makeArray({'length': '-3'})
```

Comment: *slow clap* ... Checkmarks to you for having the most complete answer and totally killing this question.  Bravo.

Answer (score 0):

You could be passing an object to the function, e.g.

```
merge ({ length: 'mylength' }, { length: 'mylength' });
```

Comment: Ah, meaning it could be an object literal with a `length` property.  Why not just check to make sure the arguments are arrays instead of doing this?

Comment: I won't just steal from Felix Kling as I think he's nailed the answer in his comment: They want the function to work not just for actual arrays but array like objects - like the jquery object e.g.

Comment: If you were to pass `{0: 0}, {1: 1}` this merge function wouldn't work.  This is why I am confused as to why we're checking type of the `length` property when it doesn't work for array-like objects anyways.

Comment: Correct - it wouldn't work, but then again *array-like* is a somewhat vague definition - which in the context means (or seems to mean simply inferring from the code): *needs a numeric length property to even attempt to loop and copy from source to destination*.

Answer (score 0):

if second is undefined or null or an object not supporting length, l will not be a number. I cannot say why second might be undefined or null as it's being passed from the caller.

Comment: Actually, if the second object was `null` or `undefined`, the code would throw a runtime error. You cannot access the property `length` of `null`.